# Prove that $a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2\leq 3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, substitution

Let $a,b,c\geq 0$ s.t. $$(a^2-a+1)(b^2-b+1)(c^2-c+1)=1.$$
I have to prove that $a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2\leq 3$.

I notice that $(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1)=(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)$.

The  solution from [$a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2\leq 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3422788/a2b2a2c2b2c2-leq-3/3423024#3423024) has a mistake.

Comment: You should take up your concern on the solution in the original question, rather than create this duplicate.  Just post below the answer given there and seek clarification.

Comment: @Ana Why do you think that my solution is wrong? Ask there your question.

Comment: @Ana I see also another proof of your inequality. If you want to see this solution, show us please, where you think my mistake in the previous proof.